# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'froala_editor'

Tags: django, docker-compose, froala

I am running django v2.2.6 on docker container, I entered django container and ran `pip install django-froala-editor`, when I run `pip freeze` it shows django-froala-editor is installed. and add I it into my installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....,
    'froala_editor',
]
```

then I used it into my model files

```
from froala_editor.fields import FroalaField
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blurb = FroalaField()
```

and actually is working fine but I still get this error every time I run the containers `docker compose up` there is a volumes attached to the containers, please note that is working fine but I am curios why it still throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by delete the container and the image, then pull the images again from the remote branch. and on the log(while creating the new container) I can see that its in installing requirements.txt file.

I think this approach is not good one, but this how I ended up doing,
if you have another please share it.